# Rails - Combining will_paginate and ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, will-paginate

I am using *Ransack* for Filtering and *will_paginate* for Pagination and it seems I have a problem combining both.

Analyzing memory problems of my app I saw that my **Category controller** was loading all entries from the database at each call.

```
def index
    @q = Category.all_cached.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30).ransack(params[:q])
    @categories = @q.result(distinct: true)
end
```

In order to get the only the first entries for each page I tried the following change:

```
def index
    @q = Category.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30).ransack(params[:q])
    @categories = @q.result(distinct: true)
end
```

Problem is that now the pagination is not working any longer. 
Error says: Couldn't find Category with 'id'=x even though enough records are available.

I have two questions:

1. How can I avoid loading all entries at first call but instead per
           page
2. As I also retrieve information about different products in
           the category and I want to avoid n+1 calls, how can I add this
           [includes(:product)] into the Category Controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
def index
  @q = Category.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 30).ransack(params[:q])
  @categories = @q.result(distinct: true).includes(:products)
end
```

Comment: That does not help. Removing the paginate(:page part from @q is calling all Categories and all Products without limit. But putting the paginate part up into the first part seems to do it. I wonder how I can resolve the issue for the show method. Seems a bit more complicated even.

Comment: Ok, I have updated it. I think you can try `def index @categories = Category.ransack(params[:q]).result(distinct: true).includes(:products).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 30) end` also

Comment: I see no difference when using the last one combined in one variable on localhost. I will deploy it and report back.